# wxWidgets program crashes when frame closed

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

My program keeps crashing when I close the frame. I've narrowed the cause down to two lines of problematic code, but I'm not sure why they're crashing. Here's some of my code:
TetrisFrame.cpp

```
TetrisFrame::TetrisFrame()
    : wxFrame(0, wxID_ANY, "Tetris")
{
    statusController_ = new StatusController;
    statusController_->setModel(new Statuses);
    statusController_->addView(this);

    tetrisController_ = new TetrisController;
    tetrisController_->setStatusController(statusController_.get());  // Problem one
    tetrisController_->setModel(new TetrisModel);
    tetrisController_->addView(new Board(this));  // Problem two
}
```

TetrisFrame class private member variables:

```
wxSharedPtr<StatusController> statusController_;
wxSharedPtr<TetrisController> tetrisController_;
```

StatusController class private section:

```
typedef wxSharedPtr<TetrisFrame> ViewPtr;
wxSharedPtr<Statuses> model_;
std::vector<ViewPtr> views_;
```

Board class private member variables:

```
wxSharedPtr<TetrisController> controller_;
```

relevant TetrisController functions:

```
void TetrisController::setStatusController(
        StatusController* statusControllerPtr)
{
    statusController_ = statusControllerPtr;
}

void TetrisController::addView(Board* viewPtr)
{
    views_.push_back(ViewPtr(viewPtr));
    viewPtr->setControlller(this);
}
```

Oddly enough problem two wasn't crashing the program until I fixed another problem that was crashing the program. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: it seems that your problem is related to memory access -- did you try running `valgrind` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that wxWidgets does its own form of memory management for widgets.  So if you are dynamically allocating the memory for a widget-type, and you then pass the address of that widget to an object that can call `delete` on it while the parent of that widget is designated by the wxWidgets run-time to destroy that widget when the parent widget is destroyed, then you're going to run into a case of double-deletion, or a case where the parent still thinks the child widget is a valid object when it's not.  A shared-pointer type will basically "own" an object ... so make sure that when you dynamically allocate an object and pass it to a shared-pointer type that you are not inadvertently making the pointer "owned" by two different memory-reclaiming pathways.

Comment: It depends ... if you use a shared or other smart pointer type, make sure that whatever dynamically allocated object you pass it will only be "managed" by that object-type.  I'm suspect especially about the `Board` object because you pass it the `this` pointer of your `TetrisFrame` object, which typically in wxWidgets means that dynamically allocated widget will be "managed" by it's parent-widget, which in this case is the `TetrisFrame` object instance.  Since I can't see all of your code, I'm just making an educated guess based on the typical wxWidgets programming paradigm.